# How do I make the html attribute's value dependent on the item being rendered by an Ember.js view?

Tags: templates, attributes, ember.js, attr

Let's say I have a view like so:

```
App.AnchorView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'a',
  attributeBindings: ['href']
});
```

and a class definition:

```
App.Item = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: "Unknown Entry",
  location: ""
});
```

and an instance of the class:

```
App.Item.create({
   name: "Google",
   location: "http://www.google.com" 
});
```

and my template is:

```
{{#view App.AnchorView}}{{name}}{{/view}}
```

and I want it to render as:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a super quick way to do it using bindAttr href and an ItemsController: http://jsfiddle.net/nLa8Z/1/ For more detailed documentation check out http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_binding-element-attributes-with-bindattr

```
{{#each App.ItemsController}}
     <a {{bindAttr href="location"}}>{{name}}</a>
{{/each}}

App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
     content: [
         App.Item.create({ name: "Google", location: "http://www.google.com"})
     ]});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically want to know if this it is possible to change it on the element generated by the view itself